# EntityListeners @Transactional do Demoiselle - Id null

Tags: java, demoiselle

Estou configurando auditoria em um projeto com `JSF` + `Hibernate` + `Demoiselle`.

**Classe Item:**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name = "itens")
@EntityListeners(value = PersistenceAuditor.class)
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Item {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
   @JsonManagedReference(value="itemParam")
   private List<ItemParam> params;
```

**Classe ItemParam:**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name = "item_params")
@EntityListeners(value = PersistenceAuditor.class)
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class ItemParam {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   @NotNull
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   @JsonBackReference(value="itemParam")
   private Item item;
```

No **PersistenceAuditor:**

```
@PostPersist
public void postPersist(Object object) {
... consome auditoria
```

E para **gravar:**

```
@Transactional    
public String insert() {
   this.itemBC.insert(this.getBean());
   return getPreviousView();
}
```

**ItemBC**

```
@BusinessController
public class ItemBC extends DelegateCrudExt<Item, Long, ItemDAO> {
```

A auditoria é persistida porém com os objetos com *id null* como se pegasse o objeto antes de ser "comitado" e eu gostaria do objeto já atualizado. Talvez por causa do *@Transactional.*

**Saída do objeto:**

```
Item{"id":69,"params":[{"id":null,"valor":10.0"}]}
ItemParam{"id":3,"valor":10.0}
```

**Onde deveria ser algo do tipo:**

```
Item{"id":69,"params":[{"id": 3,"valor":10.0"}]}
ItemParam{"id":3, "item":69, "valor":10.0}
```

Alguma ideia para resolver isso?

Comment: Tem como colocar o código da função this.itemBC.insert(this.getBean()) ? A class Item completa também ajudaria bastante!

Comment: ItemBC insert utiliza o insert direto do Demoiselle mas postei ele e também a classe item e a classe filha (ItemParam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a especificação JSR 338 (Java Persistence API, Version 2.1) na página 101:

> It is implementation-dependent as to whether callback methods are
>   invoked before or after the cascading of the lifecycle events to
>   related entities. Applications should not depend on this ordering.

Basicamente isso significa que o método postPersist do item pode ser chamado antes do itemParam ser persistido.

Se os métodos forem executados nesta ordem, o comportamento desejado seria obtido:

- persist Item
- persist ItemParam
- postPersist do Item
- postPersist do ItemParam

Mas a execução também pode acontecer nesta ordem:

- persist Item
- postPersist do Item
- persist ItemParam
- postPersist do ItemParam

Caso eles sejam executados nesta ordem, repara que o itemParam terá id null no postPersist do Item, já que o persist do itemParam ainda não foi chamado.

De acordo com a especificação do jpa o implementador (hibernate) pode executar os métodos em qualquer uma das duas ordens, então o seu código tem que ser feito para funcionar independente da ordem que hibernate resolveu escolher.

Acho melhor não usar o postPersist neste caso. Uma solução seria fazer uma função no ItemDAO que chama o persist no Item (que vai dar persist nos params em cascata) e depois consome a auditoria (e tudo já vai estar com id correto já que o persist dos params já gerou os ids).